# Debug Odoo 10 with pudb

Tags: odoo

I am trying to debug a new module.
If the following line is inserted:

```
import pudb; pudb.set_trace()
```

inside a method (previously pudb was installed by typing pip install pudb).

And the odoo server is launched via odoo-bin, shall the server stop the execution and display pudb debug screen?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you do it and see for yourself? With `pdb` it stops and you are able to inspect the variables; it should halt with pudb as well.

Comment: The procedure has been tried before -as shown by the question where the procedure is clearly described-. There was an issue with the module itself so it was not being loaded so I got no console (pdb/pudb) screen. I was checking if this was the right path. I do not understand the negative vote, question shows research effort, it is useful and it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is the rigth way to debug. I was not reaching pudb because there was some issues with the module itself. No other actions than the described above are needed to debug with PUDB in Odoo.